# how to scrollToDeltaX gridpanel to the active editor(cellediting)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i have a gridpanel with cellediting plugin, and with a lot of grid header
(at least make the grid shown it horizontal scrollbar)...
here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/AzV3c/)...

there is a bug in my grid, try to edit one of the collumn, and then press tab key to navigate to *header15*..
the grid didn't scroll to where i am editing,...
is it a bug?? a have looking for this at their [forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/search.php?searchid=489189), but no luck..

so, how to fix it??
how to make my grid scroll to the active editor??

from docs, there is a method `scrollByDeltaX`,
but how to know the delta from active editor??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut it short, [try demo first](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/DCYan/) :)

(Too free, and wanted your bounty, please award me!)

Funny that my answer works just nice on 4.0.7, but it doesn't work on 4.0.2a! Out of no clue, I checked the source of `4.0.2a`, and shockingly saw this:

In `src/panel/Table.js` (4.0.2a)

```
/**
 * Scrolls the TablePanel by deltaY
 * @param {Number} deltaY
 */
scrollByDeltaY: function(deltaY) {
    var verticalScroller = this.getVerticalScroller();

    if (verticalScroller) {
        verticalScroller.scrollByDeltaY(deltaY);
    }
},

/**
 * Scrolls the TablePanel by deltaX
 * @param {Number} deltaY
 */
scrollByDeltaX: function(deltaX) {
    var horizontalScroller = this.getVerticalScroller();

    if (horizontalScroller) {
        horizontalScroller.scrollByDeltaX(deltaX);
    }
},
```

Noticed anything? Checkout the function `scrollByDeltaX`! It's coded wrongly (fixed in 4.0.7)!!! And this will obviously wouldn't have any visual feedback. It is asking the vertical scrollbar to do a deltaX scrolling. How can it be?

Anyway, to fix this problem is rather easy, in case you do not want to upgrade to 4.0.7. *Afaik 4.0.7 has tons of bugs inherited from 4.0.6, and it breaks my project with that freaking masking issue.*

Below is my working answer, and I hope you'll appreciate it. Basically I have modified the `onEditorTab` method and created an event hook, so your `grid` can hook onto it, and do the `scrollByDeltaX` when tabbing is triggered.

I'm not too sure how to do a scroll left most/right most, so a funny `Infinity` has been used in my code out of laziness.

Here is the example: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/DCYan/)** (Remember to try out SHIFT+TAB too)

```
/**
 * Customized Row Selection Model which will
 * fires "editortab" event when an tabbing occurs
 */
Ext.define('NS.RowModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.selection.RowModel',

    //False to wrap to next row when you tab
    //to the end of a row
    preventWrap: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        /**
         * @event editortab
         * Fires when editor is tabbed
         * @param {RowModel} rowModel this rowmodel
         * @param {Editor} edt The editor
         * @param {string} dir The direction of the tab (left or right)
         * @param {Event} e The event object
         */
        this.addEvents('editortab');
        this.callParent();
    },

    //memorizing which is the last context
    lastEditorContext: null,

    onEditorTab: function(edt, e) {

        //Part of this code is from the original onEditorTab in
        //src/selection/RowModel.js line 416
        var me = this,
            view = me.views[0],
            record = edt.getActiveRecord(),
            header = edt.getActiveColumn(),
            position = view.getPosition(record, header),
            direction = e.shiftKey ? 'left' : 'right',
            newPosition  = view.walkCells(position, direction, e, this.preventWrap);

        //we store the last context, so we know whether the 
        //context has changed or not
        me.lastEditorContext = edt.context;

        //if there is new position, edit; else, complete the edit.
        if (newPosition) {
            edt.startEditByPosition(newPosition);
        }else{
            edt.completeEdit();
        }

        //If context doesn't change, we try to walk
        //to the next one until we find a new edit box (context changed)
        while (me.lastEditorContext === edt.context && newPosition) {
            newPosition = view.walkCells(newPosition, direction, e, this.preventWrap);
            if (newPosition) {
                edt.startEditByPosition(newPosition);
            }
        }

        //Fires the event
        this.fireEvent('editortab', this, edt, direction, e);
    }
});

/**
 * Customized Editor Grid to support tabbing
 */
Ext.define('NS.EditorGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1
            })],

            selModel: Ext.create('NS.RowModel', {
                listeners: {
                    editortab: {
                        fn: me.onEditorTab,
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
            })
        });

        me.callParent();
    },

    onEditorTab: function(sel, edt, dir, e) {

        var lastRow = sel.lastEditorContext.rowIdx,
            newRow = edt.context.rowIdx,
            deltaX = 0;

        //Let's calculate deltaX first

        //if row changed, we reset the cells to the left most or right most
        if (lastRow != newRow) {
            deltaX = lastRow < newRow ? -Infinity : Infinity;
        }else{
            //else, do deltax :)
            deltaX = edt.context.column.width * (dir == 'right' ? 1 : -1);
        }


        //If you are using 4.0.2a, use this. They have typo in
        //src/panel/Table.js, line 1133
        var horizontalScroller = this.getHorizontalScroller();
        if (horizontalScroller) horizontalScroller.scrollByDeltaX(deltaX);


        //But if you are running 4.0.7, this is fine. Use this:
        //this.scrollByDeltaX(deltaX);
    }
});

//-------------------------------------------------
//Everything below remains :)

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var storeSr=Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        fields: ["KD_SR","NM_SR"]
    });

    //load data
    var tmpd=[];
    for (i=1;i<=15;i++){
        tmpd.push([i,"nm "+i]);
    }
    storeSr.loadData(tmpd);

    //create column
    col=[]
    col.push({header: "Kode", dataIndex: 'KD_SR'});
    for (j=1;j<=15;j++){
        col.push({
            header: "Header"+j,
            width:100,
            dataIndex: 'NM_SR',
            editor:{xtype:"textfield"}
        });
    }

    var gridSr = Ext.create('NS.EditorGrid', {
        height: 200,
        width: 500,
        store: storeSr,
        columns: col
    });

    //create window
    var winEditSR=Ext.create("Ext.Window",{
        title:"Sub Rayon",
        autoWidth : true,
        autoHeight : true,
        autoShow:true,
        border : false,
        modal : true,
        items : [gridSr]
    }); 
});
```

I still wondering if there might be a better solution... perhaps using column (`header`)'s `x` to determine scroller's `scrollLeft`, but that will be pretty jerky...

Comment: thank you .... exactly, when i asked this question, i didn't see that sencha has released the latest version (4.0.7) .. now, i will try to migration. However, if there is a bug (s), i'll re-use 4.0.2a and your solution. once again thank you. i give you my bounty

Comment: Thanks! Love leeching points :) By the way, 4.0.7 is buggy, yes. I think they are moving forward to 4.1 very soon. The mis-positioned masking overlay is pretty serious.

Comment: oh no .. when i just change the base framework to 4.0.7, i found a bug that was in 4.0.2a does not exist .. i think i should re-use 4.0.2a..

Comment: Yea I think we should. Wait for 4.1 then. 4.0.5/6/7 seems pretty buggy.

Comment: Try adding a text such as "<TEST>" in the editor and see what happens! Do you have any solution that?